# Why is WebStorm showing a type error with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, next.js, webstorm

I'm working on a Nextjs project with [`Chart.js@4.3.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs) and [`react-chartjs-2@5.2.0`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2) and, even though compiling the project works, WebStorm says there's a type error.

Here's a MRE (Nextjs):

```
// pages/index.tsx
import { Chart, registerables }
import { Line } from 'react-charts-j2'

const Index () => {
  const chart = {
    data: {
      labels: ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'foobaz']
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Foo',
          data: [0, 1, 2, 3]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  return (
    <Line data={chart.data} />
  )
}
```

I tried passing data and labels types to `Line` like: `<Line<Array<number>, string>`, but that didn't work either. The error shown by the IDE is the following:

> Type {datasets: {data: number[], label: string}[], labels: string[]} is not assignable to type ChartData<"line", TData, TLabel>

[image: Error from WebStorm]

Environment:

- Nextjs: 13.0.6
- React: 18.2.0
- Node: 18.12.1
- Typescript: ^5.0.4

Is it something to do with my IDE or my code?

Comment: Since it looks like you might be using VSCode, maybe you can try the Pretty TypeScript Errors to see if it gives you a better description of the problem.

Comment: I would try `import { ChartData } from 'chart.js'` and use it to type `chart.data` to see if the same error shows up.

Comment: The picture there is from WebStorm. I also tried typing `chart.data` as suggested but it didn't work. I think it was just an issue with the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

It must have been an issue with my IDE, because just by disabling and reenabling `Show project errors` in Settings (`Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript`) the error disappeared.

[image: Settings capture]